# Trying to load indexed LZO file using LzoPigStorage and elephant-bird

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hdfs, lzo, elephantbird

I've got a log file with default LZO compression and an .index file generated using Hadoop-LZO, but when I run a simple Pig file to retrieve the top 100 records using LzoPigStorage, I get the following exception:

```
Message: Unexpected System Error Occured: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop23.PigJobControl.submit(PigJobControl.java:130)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop23.PigJobControl.run(PigJobControl.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher$1.run(MapReduceLauncher.java:257)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop23.PigJobControl.submit(PigJobControl.java:128)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected
    at com.twitter.elephantbird.mapreduce.input.LzoInputFormat.listStatus(LzoInputFormat.java:55)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:269)
    at com.twitter.elephantbird.mapreduce.input.LzoInputFormat.getSplits(LzoInputFormat.java:111)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigInputFormat.getSplits(PigInputFormat.java:274)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeNewSplits(JobSubmitter.java:452)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:469)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:366)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1269)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1266)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1266)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.ControlledJob.submit(ControlledJob.java:336)
```

I am running Hadoop 2.0, Pig 0.11, and elephant-bird 2.2.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use elephant-bird, so I'm not entirely sure that this is the problem.

But looking at their [build for v2.2.3](https://github.com/kevinweil/elephant-bird/blob/v2.2.3/libraries.properties), it was compiled against hadoop-0.20.2 and pig-0.9.2. I've seen problems with UDFs in Pig when running on a newer version than what the UDF was compiled against.

Are you able to upgrade elephant-bird to a newer version or recompile against the correct libraries?

Comment: What I did was I took the built elephant-bird-2.2.3.jar and copied it to my test folder. How do I check which version Hadoop and Pig it was built against? It was built on the same machine that is attempting to utilize it.

Comment: This is probably very outdated now... but it seems that you're just using a very old version of elephant bird... I'd suggest upgrading to a newer one.